# Hololens, Unity and Spatial mapping to guide users to a location

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, spatial, hololens

I've been working in a Microsoft HoloLens app using Unity 3D and HoloToolKit. My application works fine and I've gotten some basic experience developing for this device.

What I'd like to do now is to guide a user within a warehouse to an item in an specific location, similar to what's done here:

[Microsoft HoloLens picker demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UAgOmY8rLk)

Specifically, the part where a picker is walking through the warehouse and getting indications on where to make a left/right, etc. I've read a little bit about Spatial Mapping with HoloLens and I kind of understand that you could get coordinates on where you're going, and I was thinking that maybe using those coordinates you can do some sort of mapping around a room and do what the video says.

I'm not really asking for a code sample (although it would be nice to have) but could someone guide me in the right direction on how these things are made so I can start doing some testing and playing around with the device?

Thanks for the help! (I currently have no code to show, as I'm not really sure where to start).